TCP sequence number is incremented though the previous segment was not acked
Let me brief my scenario on SIP REGISTER, There is an endpoint behind NAT and gets connected to my application server over TCP via NAT device.


TCP Handshake done, endpoint(A) sent SIP REGISTER(let's say 100Bytes) to my AS, Application server responded with 200
OK(100Bytes).
Now the sequence number of TCP connections are 100bytes, Next sequence numbers are 101 and acked bytes are 100.
After few seconds, my AS sends OPTIONS request (seq no:101, next seq: 201, ACKed: 100) on the same TCP connection to see if the NAT pinhole was closed.
Indeed, the NAT pinhole was closed for that endpoint, hence the OPTIONS
request was not ACKed.
After few seconds, the endpoint behind NAT itself triggered RE-REGISTER(100bytes) to NAT device and NAT device opened another pinhole and used the same TCP
connection to send that RE-REGISTER to my AS, but it did not ACKed the above
OPTIONS bytes in TCP header (seq no: 101, next seq: 201, ACKed: 100)
My AS, upon the RE-REGISTER, sends back 200 OK with latest sequence number it maintains (seq no: 201(100(200 OK) + 100 (OPITONS)), next
seq: 301, ACKed:200) but the problem here is it does not set PUSH flag
and sets only ACK TCP flag, moreover only half of the 200 OK buffer
was sent out.
Rest of my 200 OK was sent while responding to the next RE-REGISTER from endpoint.


Could anyone please explain me what could have been went wrong here?

Can TCP connection remain open between the AS and endpoint after the NAT pinhole for the user was closed?
From server side, Can the next packet in TCP connection have continues sequence number though the previous packet was not Acked?
Why my RE-REGISTER's 200 OK was partially sent but with TCP ACK packet(PUSH was not set)?

NOTE: The TCP stack is very old i'm find it very tough to replicate this issue. Could not put the pcap out here as it has some confidential information.


It is open until both sides have received a FIN or RST. 2. Yes, of course, it isn’t the same data so it doesn’t have the same sequence number. 3. PUSH has never been relevant in TCP. It makes no difference to anything whether it’s set or not. It was designed for a mythical API that never appeared AFAIK.


@user207421 isn't the connection from the endpoint to NAT and NAT to AS are two different part? once the NAT device closes the pinhole should not the connection between NAT and AS shall be broken. NAT is not expected to send RESET after NAT pinhole closed?
